# Docker - how to add new python dependencies to the existing docker image?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, deep-learning, dockerfile

I am a novice to docker.

I am having difficulty using tensorflow docker in my Windows 10 OS.

As I am following the Udacity's deep learning course, I've downloaded the `tensorflow` docker following the [instruction](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#docker-installation) and tried to launch the first assignment.

But it failed to launch as the docker image was missing the **`scikit-learn`** package.

So basically what I do to overcome this issue is I first run my docker image:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow /bin/bash
```

and then I run:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

and then I run (might not be 100% correct but something like):

```
./run_jupyter.sh
```

to launch the iPython notebook to carry on my assignment.

My question is simple:

how do I save this change that I occurred on this docker image so I don't have to repeat this step each time I have to relaunch the notebook?

Can I do this by modifying the docker configuration file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once your container is in the right state (`scikit-learn` is installed, the script is executed), stop it (`docker stop`) and commit it as a new image.

See [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) in order to commit a container’s file changes or settings into a new image.

Then you can run that new image (with the same parameters as before), except the container created from that new image will have the previous steps already there.

But the other approach is to build your image from the [tenserflow udacity Dockerfile](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/Dockerfile).

```
FROM gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest
MAINTAINER Vincent Vanhoucke <vanhoucke@google.com>
RUN pip install scikit-learn
RUN rm -rf /notebooks/*
ADD *.ipynb /notebooks/
WORKDIR /notebooks
CMD ["/run_jupyter.sh"]
```

That image, by default, will execute the right command.

Comment: Thanks a lot VonC. This is very helpful. But in the bash shell, if I type docker stop command it doesn't recognize 'docker'. Should I first exit out of the shell first and then type docker commit?

Comment: @user8079 Yes, docker stop is be typed in the host shell, not in the container shell.

Comment: I don't think stopping the container is necessary. You can commit a running container.

Comment: @ttfreeman Interesting. I wonder if that was the case when I wrote this answer, 3+ years ago.